# Is Lame_enc threads safe?

Tags: c++

I need to know if lame_enc thread safe or not?

Comment: have you tried the documentation?

Comment: Yes ..and i found this "Although the interface is designed to be able to handle multiple parallel streams it can't be done yet due to limitations in the engine, only one stream is allowed. "  http://users.hol.gr/~dzach/vox/lame/LameDLLInterface.htm

Answer (score 2):

As of LAME 3.99.5 [HACKING](http://fossies.org/unix/misc/lame-3.99.5.tar.gz%3aa/lame-3.99.5/HACKING):

```
THREADSAFE:

Lame should now be thread safe and re-entrant. 
The only problem seems to be some OS's allocate small
stacks (< 128K) to threads launched by applictions, and this
is not enough for LAME.  Fix is to increase the stack space,
or move some of our automatic variables onto the heap with
by using bug-prove malloc()'s and free().
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure how it's done, but there is a way to boost the encoding process using multiple threads.*

See [this.](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=29811&st=0&p=257819&#entry257819)

**Update:**

The tests [here](http://techreport.com/articles.x/17545/10) say they use `Lame MT` *(multithreaded)* to benchmark the CPU. I guess this is another evidence, that lame encoding can be done in separate threads. *You might want to split your file into several chunks and process them in separate pipes.*

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply :) but i can't download Lame MT

Comment: I made a heavy test on "lame_enc" by make many threads call it and it seems threads safe..only problem encountered is huge memory consumed during encoding process